# How to replace a individual bit within a python opbject of types bytes by setting its value explicitely

Tags: python, replace, set, byte, bit

Let's assume I have a variable tmp that is of type bytes and contains zeros and ones. I want to replace the value of the fifth position within tmp by setting an explicit value (e.g. 1).

I wonder what is a clean way to replace individual bits within an object (tmp) that has type 'Bytes'. I would like to set it directly. My attempt does not work. Help in understanding the problem in my approach would highly be appreciated.

```
print(tmp)       # -> b'00101001'
print(type(tmp)) # -> <class 'bytes'>
tmp[3] =  1      # Expected b'00111001' but actually got TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a function like set_bit_in(tmp, position, bit_value)?

Comment: A `bytes` object is immutable, just like text strings are. But you can easily create a `bytearray` from it, which *is* mutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pack numbers into a bitset (python,bitwise operations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317564/pack-numbers-into-a-bitset-python-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 0):

A bytes object is an immutable object in python, you can index it an iterate it though.

You can turn it into a bytearray though, and that would be the easiest way to go about it

Or what you can do is, for example, turn it into a list, then change the value, as follows:

```
    tmp_list = list(bin(tmp)[2:])
    tmp_list[3] = '1'
```

The first two characters are stripped ([2:]) because they are always `'0b'`, of course that is optional.

Also a bytesis a string representation of a byte (hence immutable), thus the assignment you want to make is `= '1'` not `= 1`

If turning to a list, then back, is not the way you wanna go you can also just copy the string representation and change the one element you wanna change.

Alternatively you can perform bitwise operations (on the int itself), if you feel comfortable with working with binaries