# Python convert HEX number digits ASCI representation into string

Tags: python, ascii

I want to make function doing exactly this:

```
#This is my imput number
MyNumberDec = 114
MyNumberHex = hex(MyNumberDec)

print (MyNumberDec)
print (MyNumberHex)

#Output looks exactly like this:
#114
#0x8a

HexFirstDigitCharacter = MagicFunction(MyNumberHex)
HexSecondDigitCharacter = MagicFunction(MyNumberHex)
#print (HexFirstDigitCharacter )
#print (HexSecondDigitCharacter )

#I want to see this in output
#8
#A
```

What is that function?

Why I need this?
For calculating check-sum in message sending towards some industrial equipment

For example command R8:

```
N   |   HEX |   ASC
1       52      R
2       38      8
3       38      8   
4       41      A
```

Bytes 1 and 2 are command, bytes 3 and 4 are checksum
Way of calculating checksum: 0x52 + 0x38 = 8A
I have to send ASCII 8 as third byte and ASCII A as fourth byte

Maybe I dont need my magicfunction but other solution?

Comment: 114 in hex is actually 72, not 8A.

Comment: so you are asking how to get the high 4 bit as well as low 4 bit separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pack numbers into a bitset (python,bitwise operations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317564/pack-numbers-into-a-bitset-python-bitwise-operations). I know it's the opposite, but give you a hint, how to do it without string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an integer to a hex string without the preceding `'0x'` by using the string formatter:

```
MyNumberDec = 114
MyNumberHex = '%02x' % MyNumberDec
print(MyNumberHex[0])
print(MyNumberHex[1])
```

This outputs:

```
7
2
```